# Cadena de caracteres con centinela

Tags: c

Tengo que hacer un programa que me pida una cadena de caracteres, y me devuelva el tamaño sin contar el centinela ni '\0' de la cadena hasta que se tope con el centinela o el caracter '\0'. No consigo arreglarlo ya que se me queda en un bucle infinito.
Esto es lo que he hecho:

```
int pLeerCadena(char cadena[], unsigned int dim, char centinela){
int mida, i;
bool trobat = false;
printf("Introdueix nom del jugador xD: \n");
scanf("%s", cadena);
i = 0;
mida = 0;
while(trobat != true){
    if(cadena[i] == centinela || cadena[i] == '\0') {
        trobat = true;
    }

    i = i + 1;

    mida = mida + 1;
}
return mida;  }
```

Comment: Si `centinela` no es `\0`, entonces `cadena[i] != '\0' || cadena[i] != centinela` nunca puede ser `false`. `cadena[i]` no puede ser igual a `\0` e igual a algo distinto de `\0` al mismo tiempo.

Comment: No entiendo a que te refieres

Comment: Para salir del bucle, en algún momento esa expresión debe valer `false`. ¿Qué valor de `cadena[i]` consigue que esa expresión sea `false`?

Comment: Cuando se tope con el centinela o \0 no? El fallo esta ne que no se como hacerlo xD

Comment: he actualizado el codigo arriba, ahora solo falla que cuando pulso espacio no capta la palabra, es decir, si escribo "Hola prueba" solo capta "Hola"

Comment: [Te podrían votar negativamente porque sin datos de ejemplo no se logra comprender bien tu pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3794)

Comment: ¿Como haces la llamada a la función "pLeerCadena"?, puesto que en ese punto debe venir definido el valor para la variable "pLeerCadena". Lo otro,¿cual es la utilidad de la variable "unsigned int dim"?